# Unable to use Subprocess module to successfully parse and run long command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am attempting to implement [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on my machine by running a series of commands on Mac in terminal that can be found [here](https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/). I am attempting to run the port mapping commands as listed in the latter link by utilizing `subprocess` in Python.

The command I am attempting to run using `subprocess` is:

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

My Python implementation of the above command:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
commands = ['echo', '"rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080"\n', '|', 'sudo', 'pfctl', '-ef', '-']
p = Popen(['sudo', '-S']+commands, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(p.communicate('root_password\n')[1])#be able to read password for sudo from stdin
```

However, this Python script does not work, as when I run `sudo pfctl -s nat` to display all port forwarding rules on my machine my expected output

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

is not displayed to the shell.

However, running

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

does indeed produce

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

after running the display command `sudo pfctl -s nat`.

How can my `subprocess` implementation be improved so that the rule listing is outputted correctly?

**Edit**: oddly, I can run the display command `sudo pfctl -s nat` using `subprocess`

```
p = Popen(['sudo', '-S']+'pfctl -s nat'.split(), stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(p.communicate(f'myrootpassword\n')[1]))
```

To achieve the same output as `sudo pfctl -s nat` when run in the shell itself.

---

I am running the command and the Python attempt on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: Is this a common question about how to use pipe in subprocess? The recommended way is to avoid using `|` but manually create two subprocess and comminucate by `PIPE`. That's because using `shell=True` is somehow dangerous if your inputs contains anything from user.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `Popen()` to execute a pipeline of several commands, and it doesn't work that way.  That's a shell feature.

I believe you need to call `Popen()` several times, one per command, and explicitly hook their stdin/stdout to each other.

Comment: Perhaps, however, I am able to run other similar commands to product the same output as the original command itself. Please see my edit, as I describe the latter further. Can you post how you would fix the `Popen` call?

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen` explicitly escapes shell metacharacters (including `|`). For example:

```
>>> p = Popen(['echo', 'abcdefg', '|', 'wc'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
>>> p.communicate()
('abcdefg | wc\n', None)
```

Note that `abcdefg` was not piped into `wc`, because the pipe character was escaped and interpreted as a character instead of a process pipe. Thus, your command isn't being piped into sudo, since the pipe character is escaped. You can *force* `Popen` to intrepret shell metacharacters by using `shell=True` (takes a string as a command, not a list):

```
>>> p = Popen(" ".join(['echo', 'abcdefg', '|', 'wc']), stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
>>> p.communicate()
('       1       1       8\n', None)
```

Shell metacharacters are escaped for good reason if you don't trust your input (to prevent injection attacks). If you do, which I think you do since you're passing in roots pw, then just use `shell=True`.

HTH.